# What's the law about body scanners in EU? Am I legally allowed to refuse?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airport-security, eu, x-ray-machines

There are a lot of EU laws about travelling through airports. We've all seen the signs about asking for your rights. So is there any EU law about body scanners? Is there an EU law that says I am always allowed to refuse to use them?

I'm not talking about traditional <strike>X Ray machines</strike> *metal detectors* , I have no problem with them, but the newer sub-millimetre "naked" machines.

Comment: You'd be strongly advised to refuse if anyone at an airport wants **you** to go through an X-ray machine. Terrahertz is at least harmless.

Comment: I think you mean metal detectors, only hand luggage goes through x-ray machines at security

Comment: I've a had a few hand searches in Europe which were really quite invasive.  So you basically have the choice between having your privates looked at or manually handled and squeezed. Pick your poison.

Comment: Remember its "opting out" not "refusing"

Comment: @CMaster At least for a while, they really did use [x-ray backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_X-ray) machines for the body scanners at some airports. I think most or all of them have been replaced by [millimeter wave scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millimeter_wave_scanner) now, though.

Comment: @Willeke That's correct now, though the early ones actually did show a naked image of the person being scanned.

Comment: Pre-Snowden I was silent as I thought I am in tin foil territory but no longer: how hard would it to exfiltrate data from these scanners without the agents on spot knowing? And to put a name on the scans, how hard would it be to run a facial recognition against the database of people who, per the manifests, are expected to be in that machine at that time? Bonus question: what do you know actually what those scans can show, beyond what the agents see there?

Comment: @chx - if the hardware isn't set up for it, it would be very difficult for the staff to get images off it (short of phone camera at the screen type approaches). If you mean for the authorities - very easy, of course. It's hard to see how such a collection of fuzzy images of people under their clothes would be *useful* to the security services however.

Comment: Continued: Not that usefulness is necessarily a guiding principle for the security apparatus. See GCHQs hacking of Yahoo webcams, and their dissapointment that all they got was a lot of cybersex. That said, it seems a pretty unimportant aspect of state surveillance with regards to an individuals life, especially in comparison to say telecoms metadata collection.

Comment: @reirab My understanding is that they use much lower energy than penatrative xrays, but yes, I still wouldn't be keen on non-medical exposure to one.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The [EU policy](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/aviation-security-policy/scanners_en.htm) is crystal clear:

> passengers must be given the possibility of opting out from a security scanner. In this case the passenger shall be screened by an alternative screening method including at least a hand search;

The UK government, as usual in its bizarre anti freedom ways, tried to resist opt outs going so far in 2010, [per this Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2010/mar/24/airport-worker-warned-body-scanner)

> Earlier this month two women, one a Muslim, became the first people to be barred from boarding a flight at Manchester airport because they refused to go through a full-body scanner.

but as of [November 22, 2013](http://www.parliament.uk/documents/commons-vote-office/November-2013/21%20November/9-Transport-AirportSecurityScanners.pdf) you can opt out at every UK airport as well. However, if you do, they will make sure to make your life miserable: in 2017 August, I was picked for the full body scanner at Heathrow T2 and after opting out they have removed and inspected every single piece from my carry on. This was a lot of fun as I was travelling for six months and there were a *lot* of pieces. I have no idea what happens if you are late from your flight because of this charade, I caught my flight, even if barely. It took about 30-35 minutes.

Comment: The UK "opt out" is a bit of a palaver. The Home Office resented its introduction into domestic law and has done all it can to make it unenjoyable. Heathrow in particular is instructed to make your journey very miserable if you insist on opting out---expect it to take about an hour. At one point you had to fill in a form. All your bags will be hand searched as will anyone travelling with you.

Comment: I have rolled this back in light of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p Also note one CCTV for every ten person in Britain.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship of the link and this answer.

Comment: No, the relationship is between the rollback and that thing.

Comment: @Calchas confirmed, just happened to me yesterday.

Comment: Calchas suggests it may take an hour, and everything I read from airlines says to get to the airport 2 hours before your flight is due - I believe most of this "2 hours" is for clearing security. As you say you barely made your flight because of the charade, I'd be interested as to how long you'd allowed for security and how long it actually took. i.e. Do people who object to full-body scanners need to get to the airport earlier than normal recommendations?

Comment: @AndyT I was connecting...