# What's the process after a border agent sees something suspicious?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, legal

I travel a lot. And by a lot I mean a new passport per year because all the pages are stamped or filled with visas.

A couple of times I have been asked more questions than others at several borders because my history seems false, while its completely true. 
What happens if the first officer I met in a border doesn't believe me? Will they deport me or deny me entrance right there or is there a secondary questioning somewhere else?

I always have a flight back home, money, credit cards and insurance plus the correct visa for business, but I want to know if I will have a chance to prove I'm not lying or if I will depend solely on one person's opinion.

Some context: I'm a 26 year old software evangelist and you can easily see that online with photos and videos plus I usually bring with me conference material with my name on it (it actually saved me once at Barajas airport)

Edit: I also travel for pleasure and the worst situation I experienced in a border and made me ask this was while I was in between conferences and entering a country actually for tourism before departing to another event. So this is a general question and not about public speaking while traveling.

Comment: Might be a bit broad? Surely it depends on the country. Secondary questioning is common, often the final decision has to be made by a senior officer. Having a right to a quick appeal is possible (although that typically means longer detention and it's difficult to be successful). But ultimately, the burden of proof is often on you and the border guards are empowered to make a decision on your entry with a standard that's much lower than the standard that prevails in criminal cases for example.

Comment: Also, are you sure the border guards were merely concerned about your story being false and not about your interpretation of the rules? If you receive compensation for talks and the like in your activity as a software evangelist, you might be pushing the bounds of what's allowed under a business visa or visa-free visit.

Comment: Main question is if I will have a chance to prove the officers in the booth wrong or if they have the power to deport me/deny entrance without all the information.

Comment: @Relaxed on the money thing I also carry invitation letters stating I won't be payed for the talks. In theory you can't be payed by someone IN the country you are visiting because that will be considered working, but you can be payed by a foreign company, in this case the company I work for. But yeah, go try to explain the difference to a border agent.

Comment: Like I said, usually you would indeed get an opportunity to talk to someone else, especially at airports in Western Europe. In practice, they have some paperwork to do and you will be detained before a flight is available so it won't happen in 10 min at the booth. I think land borders can be harsher.

Comment: Incidentally, you might find [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p) interesting. It's just one example in one country but it gives you an insight into the process when things go really bad.

Comment: Also, it can be stressful and feel unfair, but thinking about “proving them wrong” might not be the most effective way to approach the situation.

Comment: There's a tangentially related question here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77295/what-proof-of-expertise-do-uk-immigration-accept-for-conference-speakers which may be of interest.  The question does not have enough answers yet to fully address the question, but if you monitor it for a while you might turn up something useful for your own situation.