# Does a US national need a visa to teach a paid training course in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, work

My US company offers technology training. A UK company has contacted us and would like to bring one of our people over for a week to train them onsite. Does the trainer need a work visa? If so what kind?

Comment: Just to clarify: the UK company will sign a contract with the USA company, and then the USA company pays the trainer in its usual course of business, right?

Comment: Yes.  See the following question and answer for some excellent advice https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p/77246#77246

Comment: @Moo while that thread is certainly helpful, I don't think this is a duplicate.  Teaching a paid training course is different under UK rules than speaking at a conference.  Thus duping this question to that one would, in my opinion, be misleading and confusing.  Yes, the distinction was discussed there (and ended up being decisive), but one has to read quite far into it to figure that out.  I think a clear answer to this question here would make for a better resource.