# Travelling to the US as a speaker in a conference

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens

I have been trying to find an answer to this and I receive conflicting information. I am travelling to the US for a conference and also tourism. The conference in covering part of my flight cost in cash, accommodation only for the days of the conference (3 days - I will stay 10 extra for tourism) plus $500 speaker fee.

I applied and received my ESTA but I am not sure if I need to apply for a B-1 as well or any other visa. I called the embassy but they don't provide information on this.

B-1 is not the appropriate visa either for speakers.

Comment: What is your citizenship? ESTA is authority to travel to, not to enter, the US.

Comment: I am a UK citizen

Comment: If you travel to the US with a visa, you do not need ESTA.

Comment: Related question: [What are the visa rules for UK conference speakers, at US conferences, who may be getting paid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110473/19400)

Answer (score 10):

The information you report receiving from CBP is incorrect.  The activities that VWP business visitors are allowed are statutorily the same as those allowed under the B-1 visa.  This is controlled by [8 USC 1187(a)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1187#a_1):

> The alien is applying for admission during the program as a nonimmigrant visitor (described in section 1101(a)(15)(B) of this title) for a period not exceeding 90 days.

Section 1101(a)(15)(B) is the paragraph that creates the "B" category of visitors, corresponding to B-1 and B-2 visas.

Whether you can receive a speaker fee as a visitor depends largely on *who is sponsoring the conference.*  To qualify, the sponsor must be described in 8 USC 1182(p)(1), as specified at [8 USC 1182(q)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#q):

> Any alien admitted under section 1101(a)(15)(B) of this title may accept an honorarium payment and associated incidental expenses for a usual academic activity or activities (lasting not longer than 9 days at any single institution), as defined by the Attorney General in consultation with the Secretary of Education, if such payment is offered by an institution or organization described in subsection (p)(1) and is made for services conducted for the benefit of that institution or entity and if the alien has not accepted such payment or expenses from more than 5 institutions or organizations in the previous 6-month period.

8 USC 1182(p)(1), in turn, [describes](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#p_1):

> an institution of higher education (as defined in section 1001(a) of title 20), or a related or affiliated nonprofit entity; or a nonprofit research organization or a Governmental research organization...

If the institution does not qualify, or if your plans do not comply with the constraints in §1182(q), you cannot use a B visa (or the VWP).  In that case, you would need a different category of visa.

Since §1182(q) speaks of "alien[s] admitted under section 1101(a)(15)(B)," that does leave open the question of whether VWP visitors are included, but the [federal register notice](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/FR/HTML/FR/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-79324/0-0-0-81102/0-0-0-81127.html) makes it clear that they are:

> Therefore, if an alien is coming to the United States to engage in activities for which he or she may accept honoraria under [section 1182(q)], the alien must seek admission to the United States as a B-1, rather than as a B-2 nonimmigrant. For those eligible to seek admission under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP), the corresponding WB classification (Visa Waiver/Business) is the proper one.

This provision of the law is apparently rarely used and therefore little known.  It's therefore unsurprising that CBP gave you incorrect information about it.  The Australian author Mem Fox [learned about this the hard way](https://memfox.com/unused/march-1st-2017-yes-ive-been-in-the-news/).

Comment: So to understand this correctly. the organisation is not academia rather private company, I can receive payment and admission if I am under VWB? How do I apply for WB? Or is it stamped at the entrance? 

I find it really interesting that CBP will provide a wrong answer to this question. I called 3 times and got the same.

Comment: @BBP you say that the purpose of your trip is business and they should admit you in WB status.  If they admit you as WT, though, you're still allowed to take the fee.  But only if the organization qualifies.  It sounds like it may not.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think they qualify under those organisations, they are a private company. 

However am I ok to travel with ESTA and declare my trip as business on the card? Sorry just want to check and also shall i print anything with me for the CBP officer in case they don't know the case and I end up in a similar situation like Mem Fox?

Thank you

Comment: @BBP You don't declare the purpose of your trip on the card; the card is a customs declaration, not an immigration form. You declare the purpose of your trip when you speak to the immigration officer at the border or when you are using the automated kiosk, if you do.  But just in case it isn't yet clear: if you're receiving an honorarium, you can't use the VWP or a B-1 visa; you need a different visa.  If I knew which one, I'd have answered the other question. If you decide to forego the honorarium, you won't have any trouble; attending a conference is a classic purpose for a business visitor.

Comment: OK so basically what CBP said is correct, I can visit on VWP if they pay my tickets and accommodation but cannot pay me a fee. These are considered reasonable expenses. 

However, the B1 advice from one of the CBP was wrong as it is not appropriate either. 

I guess I need to forego the fee as its not worth the potential hassle.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question here for other people who might be in a similar position:

I called CBP to inquire about it twice. Both officers said that travelling for a conference under ESTA is OK and also covering of flights and hotels expenses. However, you cannot accept a fee and be seen profiting from it.

If you want to accept a fee you need a B1 visa.

Comment: See https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

Comment: "If you want to accept a fee you need a B1 visa": this is incorrect.  See [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/116007/19400).