# Visa waiver program when receiving fee as a conference speaker

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, conferences

I will be speaking at a conference in the USA soon, where I will receive a fee and reimbursement for my travel expenses. The conference will not be held by a University, but by a private company. I have a German passport and I am currently residing in Germany. Am I eligible for the Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: see also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115994/travelling-to-the-us-as-a-speaker-in-a-conference

Comment: Thanks. As far as  I understand, I can waive my honorarium - if I choose to not get paid, I can still use my ESTA, correct?

Comment: As far as *I* understand - but I only skimmed said posts - you can take a honorarium if it comes from a non-profit organization.  See the answer to the post I linked above.