Academic Research on ESTA?
I am a PhD student at a European university, and national of an ESTA country. I will visit the US for 2 months as I informally collaborate with a professor based at a US university. I plan to conduct my own research there profiting from his advice and the opportunity to meet him more regularly, while occasionally visiting lectures or conferences there. During my stay, I will be invited to give talks at other universities and meet with other professors, or visit conferences.
I won't be paid by any US university nor work for any US institution, and I have no official affiliation with the US universities or professors I will visit. As such, I have no official invitation letter from the university or anything.
I also expect to tour the US a little bit, especially since I have a friend based where that US university is.
My understanding is that I could go to the US simply with an ESTA, as I'm not working there nor receiving US income, but conducting independent research. If so, should I mention business as my primary reason for visiting or tourism? Or should I get a visa of some sorts instead?

You'll be visiting under the "Visa Waiver Program" not ESTA (ESTA being paperwork you need to do to enter under the VWP via certain routes. You can search up information on what activities are permitted under the VWP (and the B1 and B2 categories of visa, which are mostly the same)

Another question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110473/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-uk-conference-speakers-at-us-conferences-who-may-b
