# Visa options to hold seminars in the UK

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel

What visa options are there to bring a team of people + speaker over from Malaysia to hold seminars and workshops in the UK?

Is it possible for me as an individual to sponsor them to come over?  What do I need to do to be able to sponsor them?

Can a company sponsor them to come over if the company's activities are unrelated to their field of expertise?

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77241/what-are-the-visa-rules-for-us-speakers-at-uk-conferences-who-may-be-getting-p?rq=1 -- if people are paying to attend these seminars, read those answers carefully.

Comment: @Sheens In addition to the comprehensive information in the question linked to by Kate Gregory, if you haven’t done so already you should look at https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa

Comment: Thanks!  People are paying to attend the seminars.  @Traveller .... the under PPE visa there is no provision for speaking, only for giving lectures at a higher education.  Do you think the speaker can get a PPE visa?

Comment: @Kate Gregory it says in the link that the activity must be listed under the "Permitted Activities" list in Appendix V.  But giving a seminar is not listed here.  What is listed is giving talks & speeches if "these are not organised as commercial events & will not make a profit for the organiser".  This is a commercial event since the attendees pay to attend.  So which visa can the speaker enter under?  From what I can see we can't use the business visitor visa or the PPE visa. I was told by an immigration advisor that the business visa can be used & this seems contradictory to the guidelines.

Comment: How about the question of sponsorship?  Is this a viable way to bring them over?

Comment: I don't know the answer to any of those. As a British subject traveling on a Canadian passport I have an ease of movement you may not.

Comment: @Sheens There is no such thing as a ‘business visitor visa’. The Standard Visitor visa is the appropriate option for those visiting the UK to carry out the business-related activities permitted by the Visitor Rules. If the activities intended to be carried out are not listed as allowed for a Visitor or a PPE visa, IMO there is no suitable visa route for what you want to do. You can check that using this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y which will guide you through the possible options